# Display Blob data retrieved from MySQL Database using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, blob

Using a web service, I was able to retrieve some data from a MySQL Database. The database has an image saved in it, which had the file type of BLOB. This is what my web service returns when it comes to the image:

```
<image>
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/7TaeUGhvd.....RRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQB//Z
</image>
```

Now I am having trouble making my JavaScript application convert this data and then display it as an image. I researched on it a bit and found a couple of tutorials online but somehow they did not work for me....can anyone please help me with this issue? What is the simplest way I can convert BLOB data to an image? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the blob has base64 encoded PNG data, you can use [data-uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to set data directly to image e.g.

```
var imgdata = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

$('#myimg').attr('src', "data:image/png;base64,"+imgdata)
```

Assumption here is that data returned from server is base64 encoded, but if that is not the case you can see various options but ultimately you may have to do proper conversion in server side, in that case why not just return the url to image and create a API on server side to return images from blob

Here is a jsfiddle in action http://jsfiddle.net/anuraguniyal/4DEtH/5/

Edit:
I am not sure what language you use server side but process will be same for each language e.g.

```
>>> s='\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x05\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\x8do&\xe5\x00\x00\x00\x1cIDAT\x08\xd7c\xf8\xff\xff?\xc3\x7f\x06 \x05\xc3 \x12\x84\xd01\xf1\x82X\xcd\x04\x00\x0e\xf55\xcb\xd1\x8e\x0e\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode(s)
'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
```

i.e. take all data, as will be stored in file (not the png marker too), not just raw image data and encode it

Comment: Now that I have encoded the blob to Base64, I am afraid that this piece of code is still not working...

Comment: @BurninatorDor as I have shown in jsfiddle that it works, so may be you are not correctly encoding the data

Comment: @BurninatorDor I gave added an example in python how to encode

Comment: thanks a bunch @Anurag!!....but I kinda figured out where I have been doing it wrong. I found that when I hard code the image in the html it works...but when I try to retrieve it from the div like this `var imgData = document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML;      $('#showPic').attr('src', "data:image/png;base64,"+imgData);
`...this is when it screws up! Now I am trying to figure out what is wrong with this line of code and why it cant convert the string retrieved as the src...

Comment: @BurninatorDor, so may be you select it as answer, regarding html have you checked that data is not being html encoded? why you are anyway reading it from a div?

Comment: The div is where the base64 encoded image is shown for now....since it is a sample application, it does not really matter at the moment. I just need it to work by displaying the images retrieved from the db...The div merely shows that the data is being retrieved properly...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5994/discussion-between-anurag-uniyal-and-burninatordor)